# Sort a list of years within a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, sorting, cell

I am trying to sort a set of numbers within a cell in Excel and need to maintain the same formatting. Specifically, in column A I have a set of cells with years being shown in descending order. The years are separated by a comma and a space when there is more than one year. For example:

```
  A    
1 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012
2 2015
3 2017, 2016, 2015
4 2017, 2016
```

What formula can I use so that the years in the cells now sort in ascending order so that in column B I will see:

```
  B    
1 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017
2 2015
3 2015, 2016, 20175
4 2016, 2017
```

Comment: splitting a string into an array and sorting that array before joining the array back into a string is pretty common. you should have no trouble fing examples.

Comment: You may have to consider using VBA, I don't think the formula within the cell can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Excel 2016 and the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **array-entered** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,AGGREGATE(15,7,--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))))
```

`seq_99` is a Named Formula that refers to:

```
=IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

To enter an array formula, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.

If you do this correctly, you will see in the formula bar that Excel has placed braces `{...}` around the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about the following User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Zort(s As String) As String
    Zort = ""
    If s = "" Then Exit Function
    If InStr(s, ",") = 0 Then
        Zort = s
        Exit Function
    End If

    brr = Split(Replace(s, " ", ""), ",")
    Call aSort(brr)
    Zort = Join(brr, ", ")
End Function

Public Sub aSort(ByRef InOut)

    Dim I As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
    Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant

    Low = LBound(InOut)
    Hi = UBound(InOut)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If InOut(I) > InOut(I + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If InOut(I) > InOut(I + J) Then
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
    End Sub
```

[image]